# How to code in Maple for testing a sequare Matrix

Tags: maple

I am writing a procedure in Maple for doing some optimization. Really now I want to ask Maple whether the Matrix is 2x2 or 3x3 or 4x4 and so on. And in each case of these matrices I am going to do something. Also, to know if the matrix is not sequare, i am going to do something else. I know that the command Dimension(A) gives you the dimension of the matrix, but I am not sure if it is the needed command to be used, and if it is so, how to use it?

Can any one help me in this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: The Maple documentation is going to be infinitely more valuable for questions like this. It even includes examples. See [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/Dimension).

Answer (score 1):

Questions about programming in Maple whose main focus is not on the mathematics of the algorithms are better suited for [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [mapleprimes.com](http://mapleprimes.com)

```
f := proc(M::Matrix)
        local m,n;
        (m,n) := LinearAlgebra:-Dimension(M);
        if m <> n then
           "the nonsquare case";
        elif m = 2 then
           "the 2-by-2 case";
        elif m = 3 then
           "the 3-by-3 case";
        else
           "some other case";
        end if;
     end proc:

f( Matrix(3,4) );

                        "the nonsquare case"

f( Matrix(2,2) );

                          "the 2-by-2 case"

f( Matrix(3,3) );

                          "the 3-by-3 case"

f( Matrix(4,4) );

                          "some other case"
```

Comment: So, this is the ideal one!